# HTML: div under div

Tags: html

All answers are not helping me.

Please see here: https://jsfiddle.net/prg5hc9m/1/

```
#main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#main1 {
  position: absolute;
  float:left;
}
#main2 {
  position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: inherit;
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I want `main2` to be under `main1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very clear on what you need but you cant use absolute with float. If you remove the absolutes on both the scroll section appears under the other.

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prg5hc9m/3/

```
#main {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}

#main1 {
  float:left;
}

#main2 {
  clear:left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 300px;
    float:left;
    //top: 10%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help @SamKirklandWA

Answer (score 0):

By 'under', I'm assuming you mean 'behind'. In order to do that, you need to add a `z-index`. Z-indexes start at zero, so simply give your `#main1` div a `z-index` of `1` to have it appear 'on top':

```
#main1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I've created an updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/eegj3mj8/2/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: They're overlapping (

Comment: I understand your logic here and I appreciate the effort you put forth.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block.

```
#main {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
```

}

```
#main1 {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  height: 50px;
}

#main2 {
  clear:left;
  display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 300px;
    float:left;
    //top: 10%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Please test answers before posting. This causes the scroll to break on #main2